# High Scores for game

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a high scores including player name to display on a separate form after all lives are lost in a game. I currently have this code for the high scores form - however it is only displaying the one score in the array and I am wanting to store 10 scores and also player's names.

```
Imports System.IO
'Code allows the computer to read from the text file containing player scores.'
Public Class Form3
    Dim highscore(9) As Integer ' array for highscores
    Dim playername(9) As String


    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i, value1, value2 As Integer 'player score variables

        Dim DataFile As StreamWriter
        '  Static save As String
        value1 = lblScore.Text ' assigns the players score to value1
        value2 = lblScore.Text ' assigns the players score to value2
        i = 0
        DataFile = New StreamWriter("D:\mmend12\My Documents\IPT\Projects\Brandon Moss - Major Project Assignment\Cosmic Crusade\Cosmic Crusade\bin\Debug\HighScore.txt")
        i = 0
        For i = 0 To 9
            If highscore(i) < value1 Then 'checks to see if the players score is bigger than the score
                value1 = highscore(i) ' assigns the value of highscore to value 1
                highscore(i) = value2 'assigns the players score to the highscore
                value2 = value1 ' assigns the previous highscore to value1
            End If
            lbxHighScores.Items.Add(highscore(i)) ' displays the scores
            'lbxNames.Items.Add(playername(i))
            DataFile.WriteLine(highscore(i)) ' saves the highscores to disk
            '   DataFile.WriteLine(playername(i))
        Next
        DataFile.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnShowScores_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowScores.Click
        Dim DataFile As StreamReader
        'Declares the variable name "DataFile" as an instance of StreamWriter, meaning that DataFile will behave like a StreamWriter object.'
        'Dim J As Integer
        DataFile = New StreamReader("D:\mmend12\My Documents\IPT\Projects\Brandon Moss - Major Project Assignment\Cosmic Crusade\Cosmic Crusade\bin\Debug\HighScore.txt")
        'Using the file path/address written above, a test.txt file is added in this folder.'
        'For J = 1 To 10
        'Creates a fixed loop, that loops 10 times

        For i = 0 To 9
            highscore(i) = DataFile.ReadLine
            lbxHighScores.Items.Add(DataFile.ReadLine)
        Next
        DataFile.Close()
        'Closes the data file. 
    End Sub
```

I have this code in the game form after all lives are lost:

```
If PlayersLives = 0 Then
                End If
                PlayerName = InputBox("Enter your username ")
                lblName.Text = PlayerName
                Form3.lblScore.Text = lblScoreNumber.Text
                Form3.lblPlayer.Text = lblName.Text
```

Can anyone provide assistance with this.

Comment: Use dictionary instead. Sort by value descending. easiest way

Comment: A dictionary wouldn't work if a player had two or more high scores.

Answer (score 0):

I would respectfully suggest rewriting the Form3 code as follows ..

I'm assuming that when you click on a name in the ListBox, the associated score is displayed in `LblScore`

Anyhow back to the code. This way, the code to save and load the scores is separated from your `Load` event and the code that modifies the list of high scores is also separated out. It will be easier to maintain/modify later. It's also better to manipulate data separately from controls to avoid the risk of inadvertent modification by users.

Each player and their score is now stored in instances of the class `Player`and all the players are stored in a `List (Of Player)`called `highScores`

There is also now a sub called `UpdateListBox` which uses the `highScores` list as a data source. The items to display are the `.Name` property of each player and the value that is returned when you click on the name of a player is the score which is then assigned to `lblScore` without any need for looping through arrays or lists.

```
Public Class Form3

    'Code allows the computer to read from the text file containing player scores.'
    Friend Class Player
        Public Property Score As Integer
        Public Property Name As String
    End Class

    Dim highscores As New List(Of Player) ' array for highscores

    Public Sub AddScoreIfHighEnough(player As String, score As Integer)
        'make sure that the high score list is sorted first
        highscores = highscores.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Score).ToList
        'work down though the list
        For Each plyr As Player In highscores
            'if the score is higher than the current item in the list,
            'insert the new score there and exit the loop
            If score > plyr.Score Then
                highscores.Insert(highscores.IndexOf(plyr), New Player With {.Name = player, .Score = score})
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        highscores.Add(New Player With {.Name = player, .Score = score})
        'if after the loop has completed, the number of items is
        'greater than 10, remove the lowest
        If highscores.Count > 10 Then
            highscores.Remove(highscores.Last)
        End If
        UpdateListbox()
        SaveScoreData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveScoreData()
        Using DataFile As New StreamWriter("D:\mmend12\My Documents\IPT\Projects\Brandon Moss - Major Project Assignment\Cosmic Crusade\Cosmic Crusade\bin\Debug\HighScore.txt")
            For Each plyr As Player In highscores
                DataFile.WriteLine(plyr.Name) ' saves the name to disk
                DataFile.WriteLine(plyr.Score.ToString) 'saves the score
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadScoreData()
        highscores.Clear()
        Using DataFile As New StreamReader("D:\mmend12\My Documents\IPT\Projects\Brandon Moss - Major Project Assignment\Cosmic Crusade\Cosmic Crusade\bin\Debug\HighScore.txt")
            While Not DataFile.EndOfStream
                Dim tempPlayerScore As New Player With {
                    .Name = DataFile.ReadLine, ' saves the name to disk
                    .Score = CInt(DataFile.ReadLine) 'saves the score
                    }
                highscores.Add(tempPlayerScore)
            End While
        End Using
        UpdateListbox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateListbox()
        lbxHighScores.Items.Clear()
        For Each plyr As Player In highscores
            lbxHighScores.Items.Add(plyr.Name & "  " & plyr.Score)
        Next
    End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadScoreData()
End Sub

Private Sub LbxHighScores_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbxHighScores.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not IsNothing(lbxHighScores.SelectedItem) Then
        lblScore.Text = CType(lbxHighScores.SelectedItem, Player).Score.ToString
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

In your code to add a high score, use something like

```
If PlayersLives = 0 Then
    End If
    PlayerName = InputBox("Enter your username ")
    lblName.Text = PlayerName
    form3.AddScoreIfHighEnough(lblName.Text, CInt(lblScoreNumber.Text))
    Form3.lblPlayer.Text = lblName.Text
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this code. Unfortunately when I play the game and go to the high scores form nothing appears in the list box where the high scores are supposed to be. Is there something I am missing. I have added the code you suggested for form 3 and have updated my game form to include the code as above to add to a high score.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that when I check the highscores.txt file there is nothing sitting in that file either. Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Comment: No you're not missing anything, It was something I missed. If the high score list wasn't full, the code wouldn't add an entry to the end of the list. I'll edit the answer in a sec.

Comment: Thanks for the addition of code, it is now saving to the highscores.txt file however is overrirding the scores each time so only one score and name is stored in the text file. Also it is only storing the actual player name in the list box and not the score - is there something I am missing. Much appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Hi David, did you have any luck on the issues above? Thanks again

Comment: Strange. The saving of scores works absolutely fine for me. I may have somehow posted slightly different code compared to what I'm running, so I'll edit my question to have exactly the same code. Also I'll include the score in the listbox.

Comment: Thanking you. Appreciated

Comment: Did you have any joy?